# Is it possible to use pika instead of librabbitmq with Celery

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery, pika

Is it possible to use Pika instead of Librabbitmq with celery ?

If so:

- Does it have any performance penalty?
- Do you need a special configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Celery only comes with in-built support for it's own two AMQP libraries - [py-amqp](https://github.com/celery/py-amqp) and [librabbitmq](https://github.com/celery/librabbitmq).

Librabbitmq is a C library, so it's naturally going to be faster than a pure python equivalent like py-amqp (or pika). It is however more difficult to troubleshoot a C library.